# How to securely store serial keys in MySQL and interchange them with a C# application?

Tags: c#, mysql

I've written a C# application and I want to give it to some people to test it out. Therefore, I want to secure my application with a serial key. I don't know if my application is going to be profitable, so I'm not looking for spending 500$ on a ready solution. As .NET C# application is pretty easy to disassembly and even make it a readable code, I don't want a built-in key generator. I want my application to communicate with MySQL, so for example, user enters serial key in welcome window,
and application communicates with database executing a query looking like

"FROM serials SELECT serial WHERE serial = 'user_input'",
 then see if there is any result from database.
However, I can't restrict user to do just this query, so if somebody gets login and password from the code, he can know all the serials in my database.

I know that I can run an additional intermediate application on the server, which would just connect to localhost MySQL and return a YES or NO response to the application, and not store the MySQL credentials in user application, however it's also quite expensive, and demands much work.

How can I solve this issue? Is it possible to have just application and MySQL database, to store keys and check for their correctness?

Comment: No, it's not possible. You already have the correct solution. If a user has the code, then they can access your database if it doesn't go through an intermediary service. Note that a determined user might also be able to get around the check anyway :-)

Comment: The reason the 'ready solution' is $500 is because it will take you a long time to develop a solution to this problem.  If it was as easy as your suggestion, then no-one would offer a $500 solution.   As an alternative to your single user/password, you will have to give each user a different user/password, with probably some monitoring to stop them running the code on 500 different PCs at the same time, and also stop it running after some date in the future, etc.  How long will it take you to write the code?  I bet it's more than $500 of your time.